# .NET - How to effectively search through database for multiple fields in one textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Example of search linq to sql I am using to search in multiple fields in DB table through one textbox:

```
var TheOutput = (from t in TheDC.SomeTable

                 where TheIDs.Contains(t.ID) && (
                 t.column1.Contains(TheSearchTerm) ||
                 t.column2.Contains(TheSearchTerm) ||
                 t.column3.Contains(TheSearchTerm) )           
                 select t.ID).ToList();
}
```

But it is very slow since fields are text fields (name, surname, email...). What strategy to use to make search through one textbox fast?

Comment: I would index the ID column; apart from that, I don't think there's much you can do; the query is simple and can't be more simple than that. If performance is really an issue because your table is huge then you can setup a SQL Server federation on Azure but that's quite involved. Start with indexing the ID column and see how that helps.

Comment: @frenchie it seems like the ID is not the issue here as it's in another table. You would have to index the text fields (name, surname...)

Comment: what about cloning customers table to other table or something like that and index string fields too in cloned table and search in clone table?

Comment: @MattKo: it looks like the first WHERE clause is on t.ID so that's why I think indexing would help. "Go find all the rows with ID == whatever" and then the string conditions only apply to the results of the first clause. Also, Amel, the way the query is, you'll only be able to pass a maximum of 2000 IDs per query, that's just how SQL Server is setup. If you pass in more IDs, you'll get an exception.

Comment: @frenchie yeah it just seemed to me that this `TheIDs` thing doesn't contain a lot of records. So I believe the slow part is where he's looking for a match on any of the text fields. But an index on `TheIDs` is certainly not wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this?

```
var TheOutput = TheIDs.Select(id => TheDC.SomeTable.Find(id)).Where(t => 
    t.column1.Contains(TheSearchTerm) || 
    t.column2.Contains(TheSearchTerm) || 
    t.column3.Contains(TheSearchTerm)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is the string contains that is causing the slowdown then it's worth trying a full text index.

You'd need to run something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_index_on_id ON TheDc.SomeTable(ID);
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON TheDc.SomeTable(column1, column2, column3) 
   KEY INDEX unique_index_on_id 
   WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
```

See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187317.aspx) for more info

That said it's always worth using SQL profiler (or if you're using EF the awesome [EF Profiler from Hibernating Rhinos](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof)) to confirm that the SQL being generated matches your expectations